# Styles. Css in angular

Tags: angular, angular11

How to apply common css to all components from style. Css in angular, I changed in package. Json under styles to point to styles. Css, can body suggest away other than this.

Answer (score 1):

When you add common css in `src/style.css` you can access in your html file. When you create angular project already your `style.css` mentioned in `angular.json` file. If there is not mention you should mention it like this.

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css"
    ]
```

then you can call your css in your component html file. for example your common css is

```
.login-fields {
    color: #8e8d8d;
}
```

you can call this login-fields in your html as a class.

```
<div class="login-fields">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your angular project should already contain global style.css located at `src/styles.css` if there isn't one you could create it. Then just make sure you also reference it in `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
           "src/styles.css"
          ],
```

In `style.css` you could paint all div backgrounds red, for example.

An example for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rrj6m?file=src%2Fstyles.css